# Print thread is non-uniform

Tags: creality-ender-3

I am finally unable to reach adequate printing with my Creality 3D. This is how it prints a raft

[image]

As you see, thread is non-uniform.

What can be a reason?

Printing setup:

1. Nozzle is brass, 0.4 width, new from Amazon
2. Filament is PLA
3. Nozzle temperature is 220, bed temperature is 60.
4. I am using autolevelling with BLTouch

Comment: For PLA you don't need a raft, that is used for high temperature materials that shrink considerably. 220 °C for PLA is also on the high side unless you print fast, print without raft at 200 °C and see what happens. If this works we can answer the question.

Comment: @0scar: It looks like OP's underlying problem is not that they have a raft but significant extrusion problems. Raft may have been an attempt to solve the failed bed adhesion that resulted from extrusion not working right

Comment: When you use "thread", do you mean extrusion width?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Indeed, and without the raft it is easier to see what the problems are.

Comment: if you found the problem, please paste it as an answer to this question and draw the followup to a new question. Defective boards happen occasionally - if this is a new printer, write to your seller that the board seems defective and you would like replacement. Otherwise, a boardswap is *relatively* easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a problem: it is with extruder motor driver.

I tried to control the extruder with the knob and saw it that rotates with strange sounds and jerkily. Then I connect extruder cable to the socket of Z-axis on motherboard and also tried to control it with the knob. This time I found it rotates smoothly.

I.e. motor is good, cable is good, motherboard 4th driver is not good.